# How to be explicit with data context?

Tags: meteor

Beginner question here: I'm working through the [Discover Meteor book, Chapter 3 on Templates](https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/templates). This line of the template gives me pause:

```
<h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
```

What's going on here is the `{{domain}}` expression is coming from the `postItem` template helper and the `{{url}}` and `{{title}}` expressions are coming from the `postsList` template helper. However, by just looking at the template, there is no way to tell which expression is handled by which template helper. I understand you can make the template more explicit by using the `this` keyword in the template. However, instead of doing this, is there a way I can explicitly create a helper in the `postItem` template? For example, I tried doing this, but it did not work:

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
  title: this.title,
  url: this.url,
  domain: function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.url;
    return a.hostname;
  }
});
```

And I don't understand why this would not work. I understand this may make the code more verbose, but personally, I would prefer the code to be more explicit than leaving it ambiguous.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my preferred way to be explicit about data context using Blaze in Meteor.

You can see a working example here :

http://meteorpad.com/pad/rkybNCiKBpzEdcfHc/Template%20Parameters

I provide each child template an explicit list of parameters like this :

```
{{> player name=this.name score=this.score}}
```

In this example, each list item will only need to display a user's name and their score.  So, the child template gets only two variables as its data context, name and score, and nothing else.
This helps me debug issues and define exactly which fields a template needs.

```
//   Parent Template
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
  players: function () {
    return Players.find({}, { sort: { score: -1, name: 1 } });
  }
});

<template name="leaderboard">
  {{#each players}}
    {{> player name=this.name score=this.score}}
  {{/each}}
</template>


//   Child Template
<template name="player">
  <div>{{userName}} : {{userScore}}</div>
</template>

Template.player.helpers({
  userName: function() {
    return this.name;
  },
  userScore: function(){
    return this.score;
  }
});
```

Inside the template it can also be a good idea to throw errors if the data context fields are not available or the wrong type.

When I started with Meteor I had the very same question and it seemed awkward to me to have this idea of implied data context.

Comment: To each his own but that feels like so much overhead that loses the simple elegance of blaze! Especially changing field names along the way.

Comment: yeah, I agree it is kind of verbose.  For me it helps to debug things.

Comment: So, more out of curiosity, why do you need to return `this.name` from a function? Why doesn't `userName: this.name` work?

Comment: @DarielDato-on I don't know.  My guess is that 'this' in a helper declaration like so ,  username : this.name,    is referring to the helper block itself, not what you are expecting which is your meaningful data context. The reason why 'this' inside a helper function is set to the template data context is that behind the scenes Meteor might be invoking the helpers using javascript's function.call() or function.apply  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply .  call() and apply() can set what 'this' is inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of what's going on is a bit off. Let me attempt to clarify what's going on.

The two templates are:

```
<template name="postsList">
  <div class="posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="postItem">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

1. The `postList` template includes an *iterator* `{{#each posts}}`
2. This iterator gets its data from the `posts` helper of the `postItem` template
3. The helper returns a *cursor* which is the result of performing a `find()` on a collection. Alternatively this helper could return an array of objects.
4. A cursor is *reactive* meaning that items can be added, removed or changed at any time without you needing to write code to update the DOM. Magic.
5. Inside the iterator the `postItem` template is included.
6. For each iteration of the iterator a *data context* is created which is a single object.
7. In javascript the current data context will be in `this`
8. In the spacebars you can access any field in the object simply by putting that field's name in double curly braces ex: `{{title}}`
9. If you wanted to be more explicit you could also use `{{this.title}}`

Sometimes the object doesn't have all the data you need to display. You might need to reformat existing fields, combine them someway, convert them (ex: UTC to local time, $ to £ etc...), or lookup related data from a different collection. In those cases you need a *helper* to return the extra piece of data.

Directly manipulating the DOM in a helper in the way you're showing is unadvisable. Since helpers can be called repeatedly even with the same data context you would likely end up with many more `a` elements than you expected.

In practice the distinction between a field value from the current data context and a helper value doesn't really matter to the presentation layer. It's not something that gets in your way of developing in Meteor. The common thing that crops up is that you insert a `{{mything}}` in the markup but forget to define a helper for it and then it shows up as blank. Or you believe that your object has a key that it doesn't have and you also get a blank.

Comment: Thanks! That explanation does help clear things up. I guess it's just a different way of thinking about it because, as you said, the view layer does not distinguish between the data context and a helper value. But wouldn't this cause problems if you created a helper that overwrote a data context?  For example, if you also had a helper called `title` then it would be unclear if `{{title}}` refers to the helper or the data context.

Comment: I'm not sure but I expect a field would take precedence over a helper of the same name.